# How to get silver tinge like screen 

Tags: android

I want to develop an application made in android and work like `mirror`. So i want to make screen which have `silver tinge`.

thanks

Comment: my appologies havent write the clear question.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
silver
#C0C0C0
rgb(192,192,192)
```

http://service.real.com/help/library/guides/realone/ProductionGuide/HTML/htmfiles/colors.htm

Answer (score 1):

# COCOCO

why dont you use color picker or any thing else or can easily find the thing over google as well

Answer (score 1):

```
#c0c0c0 is the hex code for silver
```

also see this http://htmlhelp.com/cgi-bin/color.cgi

Comment: There are multiple shades of gray. #ffffff is white while #000000 is black. #eeeeee, #dddddd, #cccccc will get you shades of gray. Experiment and see which one works best for you.

Comment: Pleae edit the answer again. So that I can remove my vote down. @bigstones: earlier the answer was different from C0C0C0.

Comment: @Gaurav, apologies, my mistake. Corrected it.